# Image is pixelating when scaled down only on older monitors

Tags: image-quality, pixelation

I'm having a weird issue that when some images are scaled down they start pixelating **only** on older monitors. (I'm guessing newer ones are Retina). I would expect this behavior when scaling up but down I would expect it to look better.

** Full-Size Image**

[image]

**Scaled-Down Image**

[image]

I am scaling down on a webpage using css (`width: 200px; height: auto`).

On one monitor I did notice the issue when scaling down just in Mac Preview. On another old monitor, I didn't see it on Mac Preview but only on the webpage.

The one thing I am noticing is that the images look like they may have been photoshopped and vectors may have been used in it.  I did try Saving for Web but that did not help.  Also, if I zoom in on my browser the image looks good.

Comment: Thay're pixellating because you are literally hitting the pixel limit. You can't really expect better than that. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwn52.png which is a screen-cap of photoshop showing individual pixels.

Comment: Hmm how would I go around fixing that

Comment: Use a bigger image. You can't get any more resolution from a picture 200px wide. That's less than a quarter the resolution of a macOS icon file, at 512.

Comment: I don't think there is a fix. It's not an error. You are just being aware of the pixels. That said, the scaling in browsers isn't always as nice as Photoshop's bicubic scaling. So if you are really annoyed you need to make downscaled versions of your image and complicate your website's code by having several different images for different scaling. I would just try to live with it.

Comment: I just scaled down in photoshop to 200px and resaved and it looks good.

Comment: If viewed on a Retina screen, the OS itself will be doing some smoothing. Don't expect most people, on Windows, to be so lucky.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Windows 10 also scales and smooths raster images in browsers (and other software) for high resolution displays.